# How to assemble small n-d arrays into a larger n-d array?

Tags: matlab

The code below produces a cell array containing *n* (=210) `2x3x4`-shaped n-d arrays.

```
n = prod(5:7);
makendarray = @(i) reshape(1:24, 2:4) + (i * 1000);
ndarrays = cellfun(makendarray, num2cell(1:n), 'un', 0);
```

For each *i* ∈ {1, … ,*n*}, the contents of the *i*-th n-d array are all integers whose initial digits match those of *i*.  For example, for *i* = 123:

```
>> ndarrays{123}

ans(:,:,1) =

      123001      123003      123005
      123002      123004      123006


ans(:,:,2) =

      123007      123009      123011
      123008      123010      123012


ans(:,:,3) =

      123013      123015      123017
      123014      123016      123018


ans(:,:,4) =

      123019      123021      123023
      123020      123022      123024
```

I want to assemble all these n-d arrays into a larger `[5x6x7x2x3x4 double]` n-d array `X` in such a way that expressions of the form `X(i,j,k,:,:,:)` will correspond to one of the original smaller n-d arrays.  This last requirement is the one that's giving me difficulty.

I have no problem producing the larger `[5x6x7x2x3x4 double]` n-d array from the smaller ones, but expressions of the form `X(i,j,k,:,:,:)` do not produce one of the original smaller n-d arrays.

Below is an example of one of the things I've tried; the last output should match below should match the output shown for `ndarrays{123}` above, but doesn't:

```
>> X = reshape(cell2mat(ndarrays), [5:7 2:4]);
>> [idx{1:3}] = ind2sub(5:7, 123);
>> squeeze(X(idx{:}, :, :, :))

ans(:,:,1) =

       62001       62003       62005
      167001      167003      167005


ans(:,:,2) =

       62007       62009       62011
      167007      167009      167011


ans(:,:,3) =

       62013       62015       62017
      167013      167015      167017


ans(:,:,4) =

       62019       62021       62023
      167019      167021      167023
```

---

**EDIT:** OK, by (pretty much blind) trial-and-error I found that the following does the trick:

```
tmp = cellfun(@(c) reshape(c, [1 24]), ndarrays, 'un', 0);
X = reshape(cat(1, tmp{:}), [5:7 2:4]);
```

IOW: linearize the subarrays before passing them to `cat(1, ...)`.  I'm surprised that it's necessary to explicitly perform this linearization step: it's what I expect MATLAB to do by default (in `cell2mat`, for example).

Be that as it may, is there a better (or at least clearer/easier to understand) way to achieve the same effect?

(BTW, for this problem, the initial shape of `ndarray` is given and not subject to change.  IOW, solutions that require modifying the `makesubarray` function in the example do not fit the situation I'm dealing with.)

**EDIT2:** In reference to Luis Mendo's answer, here's the output (copy-pasted verbatim from my MATLAB workspace) of a small script (with `echo on`), showing the sizes of various items:

```
n = prod(5:7);
makendarray = @(i) reshape(1:24, 2:4) + (i * 1000);
ndarrays = cellfun(makendarray, num2cell(1:n), 'un', 0);
size(ndarrays)

ans =

     1   210

size(permute(ndarrays, [2 3 4 1]))

ans =

   210     1

size(cell2mat(permute(ndarrays, [2 3 4 1])))

ans =

   420     3     4

echo off;
```

Comment: If your upper limit of the initial digits is 210, what would you want  `X(2,9,9,:,:,:)` to contain? Note that your output array `X` needs to be defined for those indices

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; the output array `X` has `size` equal to `5 6 7 2 3 4`, so the maximum index I expect would be `X(5,6,7,2,3,4)`.  BTW, the index for the 210-th subarray would be `X(5,6,7,:,:,:)`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I think I misunderstood

Comment: @LuisMendo: no prob; BTW, I found an answer, but it's pretty clueless; see my EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with a little bit of `permute` and `reshape`. The logic of this approach can be followed by observing `size(X)` at the end of each step (indicated in the comments):

```
X = cell2mat(permute(ndarrays(:), [2 3 4 1])); %// size [2 3 4 210]
X = permute(X, [4 5 6 1 2 3]); %// size [210  1  1  2  3  4]
X = reshape(X, [7 6 5 2 3 4]); %// size [7  6  5  2  3  4]
X = permute(X, [3 2 1 4 5 6]); %// size [5  6  7  2  3  4]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an intriguing approach.  I must admit that I'm still trying to figure out the reasoning/logic behind it.  Also, I get different `size`s from yours: `size(ndarrays) -> [1 210]`, `size(permute(ndarrays, [2 3 4 1])) -> [210 1]`, and `size(cell2mat(permute(ndarrays, [2 3 4 1]))) -> [420 3 4]`.  Are you starting from the `ndarrays` cell array produced by the code I posted at the beginning of my question?  If so, I'm baffled by the `size [2 3 4 210]` on the first line of your listing.  (I have not looked into the remaining ones.)

Comment: @kjo Yes, I use the `ndarrays` in your example (a cell array containing 210 cells, where each cell is a 2x3x4 array). My first line just concatenates all cells (each of size [2 3 4]) along a fourth dimension. That's why the result is [2 3 4 210]. BTW, `size(permute(ndarrays, [2 3 4 1]))` should be [1 1 1 210], right?

Comment: For `size(permute(ndarrays, [2 3 4 1]))`, I get `[210 1]`, not `[1 1 1 210]`.  There seems to be some substantial difference between what we are each calling `ndarrays`.  I've added a full listing of what I'm doing in an **EDIT2** section of my post.

Comment: @kjo The problem is that in your Edit 2 you're omitting the final `'` in the `ndarrays` line. You did have that `'` in your original example. I've modified my answer code (adding `(:)` in my first line) to handle both cases.

Comment: My apologies!!!  I missed the stray `'`; it shouldn't have been there.  I've fixed the error.

Comment: @kjo No problem. Now my answer is more robust :-)

Comment: I would have never thought of using `permute` like you do on your first line!  Very cool.